# Python format string for percentage with space before %

Tags: python, string, format, percentage

I'd like to format a number as percentage, i.e. `0.331 -> '33.1 %'`.

The obvious way in simple code is to use `'{:.1f} %'.format(percentage*100)`
Since I am only passing the format string to a function as in `fn(dataframe, format='{:.1f}')`, I cannot easily multiply the data with 100 (since data is used for calculations inside the function as well). Now Python has the `%` format specifier which *almost* does what I want:
`'{:.1%}'.format(0.331)` gives `'33.1%'`, but I want `'33.1 %'` (as required by DIN 5008)

Is there a way to use insert the space between the number and percent symbol using the format string? So basically like `'{:6.1%}'.format(0.331)` but with the space on the other side of the number.

If that's not possible, I have to crack open the function the format string is passed to. And that seems a hacky solution that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest as a lazy programmer myself I would just use `str.replace` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) after the formatting appended like this:

```
a = '{:.1%}'.format(0.331).replace('%', ' %')
print(a)
```

gives: `33.1 %`

Comment: Since the function I am calling produces a larger output (css+html, created by  pandas.DataFrame.style.render), I don't want to do string replacement afterwards.

Comment: I get that but I don't think there is a way to do that with the format so you either have to write your own function that formats the string for you or you have to do it afterwards I think.

Comment: hm. Ok, I have a "solution". Multiply data with 100, and as a first step inside the calculate function, I divide by 100 if a boolean parameter "isNormalized" is true. Then I can simply use '{:.1f} %'. Not nice but works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use f'' strings:

```
num = .331 
print(f'the percent is {num*100:6.2f} %')

the percent is   0.33 %
```

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked how to use f-strings?

```
number_1 = 0.331

string_1 = f'{number_1 * 100} %'

print(string_1)

output: 33.1 %
```